# this.mixIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, encryption

I was trying to encrypt an input value and save it in database then decrypt and show it . I searched for a good and secure way so I found CryptoJS, the problem is this :

**Uncaught TypeError: this.mixIn is not a function**

I don't know what to do and there is no answers about this problem .

I've tried a different versions of aes.js and the problem is still showing up .

this is the code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#message").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
     var message= $("#message").val();
     var Encryptedmessage = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, "/");
     post_data = {'messagephp':Encryptedmessage};
       $.post('test.php', post_data, function(data) {
         $( "#results" ).html( data );
       });
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CryptoJS no method mixIn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601095/cryptojs-no-method-mixin)

Answer (score 2):

```
post_data = {'messagephp':Encryptedmessage} -> post_data = {'messagephp':Encryptedmessage.toString()}
```